# Transfering app data to other android device

Tags: file-management, data-transfer

I have lot of data written by ColorNote application. Now I installed the ColorNote in other Android device, too.

Now, how to copy my ColorNote data to from the original device to that device (with the fresh installation of ColorNote)?

I don't know where ColorNote writes data written by its user :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Colornote](https://www.colornote.com/sync-notes-between-phone-and-tablet/) support page gives a few options. You can sync through their online services, by transferable backup, or by SD card.

> How to transfer notes from old phone to new phone.
>
> Using the online sync is Recommended.
>
> Sign up online sync on your old phone. Go to:

`Menu –-> Backup –-> Sign Up.`

> next Sync your device by going to:

`Menu –-> Sync. Check how many notes are synced by going to: Menu -–> Settings –-> Online Backup –-> Synced notes.`

> Then sign in to online sync in your new phone by going to:

`Menu –-> Backup -–> Sign In.`

> Using sdcard backup:
>
> the steps below to transfer notes saved on the previous device to the new device using local backup.
>
> When you have the previous device
>   Open ColorNote and go to the device backup screen on the previous device go to:

`Menu --> Backup --> Tap Device`

> Which is located in the upper bar or go to:

`Settings --> Backup.`

> Next manually back up notes by pressing:

`Backup Notes --> Enter master password --> Done.`

> then move the backed up files from the previous device to the new device.
>
> Go to sdcard backup screen on your old phone by:

`Menu –-> Backup -–> SD card backup.`

> To Backup Notes you need to press the button and then enter your master password.
>
> Lastly, move sdcard from old phone to new phone.
>
> Go to sdcard backup screen on your new phone and tap backup item you want to restore.
>
> finish up by typing the  password that you have set when backup file was created.